# Получаю ошибку TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'RelatedManager' при POST запросе к API

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

У меня есть сериалайзер для создания рецепта. При POST запросе на соответствующий адрес получаю ошибку `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'RelatedManager'` При этом объект создается, записи в таблицы записываются. В чем может быть дело?

```
class RecipesCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = CustomUserSerializer(read_only=True)
    ingredients = IngredientWriteSerializer(many=True)
    tags = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Tags.objects.all(),
                                              many=True)

    def create_tags(self, tags, recipes):
        for tags in tags:
            recipes.tags.add(tags)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ingredients_data = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
        tags = validated_data.pop('tags')

        new_recipes = Recipes.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for data in ingredients_data:
            ingr = get_object_or_404(Ingredients, pk=data['id'])
            amount = data['amount']
            IngredientsAmount.objects.create(recipes=new_recipes,
                                             ingredients=ingr,
                                             amount=amount)
        self.create_tags(recipes=new_recipes,
                         tags=tags)

        return new_recipes

    class Meta:
        model = Recipes
        fields = ('author',
                  'ingredients',
                  'tags',
                  'image',
                  'name',
                  'text',
                  'cooking_time')
```

связанный сериалайзер

```
class IngredientWriteSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    amount = serializers.IntegerField()
```

Модели:

```
class Recipes(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               db_index=True,
                               related_name='recipes',
                               verbose_name='Автор рецепта'
                               )
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredients,
                                         through='IngredientsAmount',
                                         related_name='recipes',
                                         verbose_name='Ингредиенты')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags,
                                  # through='RecipesTags',
                                  related_name='recipes_tags',
                                  verbose_name='Теги')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True,
                            verbose_name='Название рецепта')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='recipes/', blank=True,
                              verbose_name='Загрузить фото')
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание')
    cooking_time = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1, 'Установите не меньше 1 минуты'), ],
        verbose_name='Время приготовления')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Рецепт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Рецепты'
        ordering = ('-id',)


class IngredientsAmount(models.Model):
    ingredients = models.ForeignKey(Ingredients,
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    related_name='amount',
                                    verbose_name='Ингредиенты', )
    recipes = models.ForeignKey(Recipes,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='amount',
                                verbose_name='Рецепты', )
    amount = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.amount

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['ingredients', 'recipes'],
                name='unique_ingredients_in_recipes'
            )
        ]
        verbose_name = 'Количество ингредиента'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Количество ингредиентов'
```

Трейсбек ошибки

```
Internal Server Error: /api/recipes/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vladimir/Dev/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/vladimir/Dev/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/vladimir/Dev/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/vladimir/Dev/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vladimir/Dev/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vladimir/Dev/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/vladimir/Dev/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/vladimir/Dev/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/vladimir/Dev/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vladimir/Dev/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 20, in create
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
  File "/home/vladimir/Dev/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 548, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "/home/vladimir/Dev/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 246, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/home/vladimir/Dev/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 515, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/home/vladimir/Dev/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 663, in to_representation
    return [
  File "/home/vladimir/Dev/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 664, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/home/vladimir/Dev/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 515, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/home/vladimir/Dev/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 963, in to_representation
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'RelatedManager'
[17/Jul/2022 13:20:57] "POST /api/recipes/ HTTP/1.1" 500 20320
```

Comment: Нужен стектрейс ошибки

Answer (score 0):

1. 

```
tags = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Tags.objects.all(),
                                              many=True)
```

Данный код кажется мне странным. Разве сериализатор не должен автоматически делать подобную операцию без необходимости в явном указании типа поля ? Попробуйте убрать эту строчку.

Так-же возможно, стоит обратить внимение на ManyRelatedField, но я совсем не уверен.

2.

```
class IngredientWriteSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    amount = serializers.IntegerField()
```

Почему так ? Разве это не будет правильно решить при помощи:

```
class IngredientWriteSerializer( serializers.ModelSerializer ):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredients
        fields = ( 'pk', 'amount' )
```

Comment: Спасибо, п.1 действительно без явного переопределения код работает, а вот п.2 ждет на вход int(), если ему дать вместо int() pk - ругается. С ошибкой разобрался переопределением def to_representation(self, instance). Не все, правда, работает как надо, но обозначенная проблема ушла.

Comment: Zuma, это хорошо что проблема ушла, но, если в сериализаторе переопределяеться метод to_representation , это говорит о том, что что-то не так. Так-же нужно учитывать что pk это в своем понимании тот же самый id, и оба в своем понимании имеют числовой тип.

Comment: В общем, я могу лишь сказать, что не знаю как именно ты решил проблему переопределением to_representation, но уверен что это не правильный подход, скорее всего, в решении Твоей проблемы, тебе поможет взгляд на ситуацию с другой стороны, или рефакторинг кода

Comment: И поля Author, Ingridients и Tags в RecipesCreateSerializer, так-же кажутся мне странными, думаю можно было применить более простой подход.
Например, если Author подрузумевает пользователя, отправившего запрос на создания рецепта, то скорее всего, правильным решением будет определить поле Author как serilizers.HiddenField( default = serilizers.CurrentUserDefault() ) , а поля Ingridients и Tags, как я понимаю вовсе не нуждаются в явном переопределении поля, в прочем, я не знаю как работает у Тебя все, и какая во всем этом лежит идея, по этому не уверен в дельности своих советов